# Why is this regular expression invalid?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why this is invalid regular expression?

```
/(?<=^|;)\s*([^:]+)\s*:\s*([^;]+)\s*/g
```

I have checked on below link, it is working fine, but in my code it is giving error. Please help.

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Check out again, on the left you can select the language, select Javascript and you'll see it's invalid (no positive lookbehind in JS)

Comment: I am new to regex, may be i have to learn more about it

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has only had lookaheads; lookbehinds (`(?<=...)`, `(?<!...)`) will give you an error.

Lookbehinds were proposed for JavaScript in [TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind), but not yet adopted into a standard.